# How to close a Fancy Box (lightbox) from an iFrame on a different domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox

I have a Google Chrome Extension that uses Fancybox (http://fancybox.net/) to show a login form.

After a user logs in or registers I would like to automatically close the lightbox. The Fancybox is hosted locally in the Chrome Extension while the login form is on our domain.

Is there a way for the iFrame (our domain) to call a function to close the Fancybox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You'll have to use cross-window messaging and postMessage.  This allows your extension to post a message, and your iframe to receive it.  You'll need code on both ends (to send and receive the message).

Here's a good tutorial (not chrome extension specific): http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage